# How can i have more than three gauge sectors in flexdashboard?

Tags: r, flexdashboard

Flexdashboard allows to specify three sectors for its gauges: "danger", "warning" and "success". I want to use 5 gauge sectors to show in which interval my observed value lies. I calculated confidence intervals with alpha 0.2 (80 %) and 0.01 (99 %) and use this to define 5 sectors:

```
Sector 1 = c(min(value),lower_90_ci)
Sector 2 = c(lower_90_ci,lower_80_ci)
Sector 3 = c(lower_80_ci, upper_80_ci)
Sector 4 = c(upper_80_ci, upper_90_ci)
Sector 5 = c(upper_90_ci, max(value))
```

This is a standard-gauge in flexdashboard:

```
library(flexdashboard)

gauge(42, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%', gaugeSectors(
  success = c(80, 100), warning = c(40, 79), danger = c(0, 39)
))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to have optimum range in the middle with warning and danger on both higher and lower sides, I tried this:

```
gauge(value = 95,  # For example
      min = 0,
      max = 100,
      sectors = gaugeSectors(
        success = c(20, 80),
        warning = c(10, 90),
        danger = c(0, 100)
        )
      )
```

You may want to make sure that the sectors covers the whole range (min-max).  Any value within the range but not belonging to any sector will use default color (success).

Answer (score 1):

Like Niels proposes, a workaround is to adjust the color in the gaugeSectors() to be depended on the input.

For example, 5 colors on the interval 0-100:

```
gaugecol <- c("#9ceb34","#D2D64C","#ebb134","#FF8C00","purple")
names(gaugecol) <- c("L","ML","M","MH","H")
quintile <- cut(input$x, breaks = seq(0,100,length = 6),c("L","ML","M","MH","H") )

gauge(input$x,
        min = 0, 
        max = 100, 
        sectors = gaugeSectors(success = c(0,100),
                               colors = gaugecol[quintile])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done out of the box. Digging into the `resolveSectors` function shows that it expects three sectors and is quite inflexible:

```
function (sectors, min, max) 
{
    if (is.null(sectors)) {
        sectors = sectors(success = c(min, max), warning = NULL, 
            danger = NULL, colors = c("success", "warning", "danger"))
    }
    if (is.null(sectors$success) && is.null(sectors$warning) && 
        is.null(sectors$danger)) {
        sectors$success <- c(min, max)
    }
    if (is.null(sectors$colors)) 
        sectors$colors <- c("success", "warning", "danger")
    customSectors <- list()
    addSector <- function(sector, color) {
        if (!is.null(sector)) {
            if (!is.numeric(sector) || length(sector) != 2) 
                stop("sectors must be numeric vectors of length 2", 
                  call. = FALSE)
            customSectors[[length(customSectors) + 1]] <<- list(lo = sector[[1]], 
                hi = sector[[2]], color = color)
        }
    }
    sectors$colors <- rep_len(sectors$colors, 3)
    addSector(sectors$success, sectors$colors[[1]])
    addSector(sectors$warning, sectors$colors[[2]])
    addSector(sectors$danger, sectors$colors[[3]])
    customSectors
}
<environment: namespace:flexdashboard>
```

Nevertheless, you could build your own `gauge` function that uses a custom built `resolveSectors` function (using the current function as a template) that expects five sectors.

Comment: Thank you! I also just thought about a workaround using a function before i use gauge() that defines the colors and hands them as variable to the gaugeSectors(colors= c(color1,color2,color3)-argument.